# vba script to add items to SharePoint online list

Tags: sharepoint-online, office, vba

I have a vba script which captures the user input from the outlook and updates an excel sheet.
I want the vba script to write into a sharepoint list in a SharePoint online site.
Please let me know how to achieve this functionality.
Any links will be helpful.

Thanks in advance,
Hepsi

Answer (score 1):

You can try this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37434198/add-items-in-sharepoint-office-365-list-using-vba-giving-error-access-denied

But here you make sure the excel account should have rights to SharePoint online account other wise you will receive access denied error